# Multiple buttons with addListenerOnButton

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create an application with 4 buttons on the main page. Each button is linked to a new xml page, however I'm having troubles using the 'AddListenerOnButton'. It's working for the first one, but for some reason not the 2.,3. and fourth.
I have updated the xml-manifest with each of the activities for the 4 xml button/pages references.

Each xml page has their own .class, as you can see in my code.

Here's my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.nutritiontest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton imagebtn1;
    ImageButton imagebtn2;
    ImageButton imagebtn3;
    ImageButton imagebtn4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        imagebtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.knapA);
        imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (getApplicationContext(), activityA.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton1() {
        imagebtn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.knapB);
        imagebtn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (getApplicationContext(), activityB.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }

public void addListenerOnButton2() {
    imagebtn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.knapC);
    imagebtn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent
                    (getApplicationContext(), activityC.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}

public void addListenerOnButton3() {
    imagebtn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.knapD);
    imagebtn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent
                    (getApplicationContext(), activityD.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}

}
```

I'm very new to android developing so all help would be appreciated

Comment: Oh god, can't believe i missed that.. Thanks a lot for the quick answers guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only call the method which initializes the first button, you have to call the other three too!

Try this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnButton1();
        addListenerOnButton2();
        addListenerOnButton3();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You call only to the addListenerOnButton() method. You need to add calls for the 3 other methods also (addListenerOnButton1,addListenerOnButton2addListenerOnButton3).

Answer (score 1):

you should add those 3 calls to your onCreate method

```
addListenerOnButton1()
addListenerOnButton2()
addListenerOnButton3()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use the same Activity as a listener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(this)
    imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(this)
    imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(this)
    imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(this)
    ...
}
```

Then on the OnClick just filter out with the button with a simple if/elseif:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(view == imagebtn1){
        //do stuff
    }else if (view == imagebtn2){
        //do stuf
    }else if (view == imagebtn3){
        //do stuf
    }else if (view == imagebtn4){
        //do stuf
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have addressed what your current issue is but I would like to provide an alternate way to do this which, IMHO, will be cleaner and less code.

First, just add the same `listener` to all `Buttons` in your `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    imagebtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}
```

then create the `onClick()` method and switch on the `id` of the `Button` clicked and change the class you want to go to

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     String nextAct = null;                    // name for Activity to start with Intent
     String shield = "com.example.nutritiontest.";  // set package name
     int flag = -1;

     switch (v.getId())  // get the id of the View clicked
                             // and compare below
     {
        case (R.id.knapA):
           nextAct = package + "activityA";
           break;
        case (R.id.knapB):
           nextAct = package + "activityB";
           break;
        case (R.id.knapC):
           nextAct = package  + "activityC"; 
           break;
           default:
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity .this, "Item currently not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    try 
    {
    if (nextAct != null)
    {
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity .this, Class.forName(nextAct));
        flag = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT;
        if (flag != -1)
        {   intent.setFlags(flag);  }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then you will want to implement the `OnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

It might look complicated or messy at first but it really isn't once you break it down. You can even remove the bits with the `Flags` if you don't need them. I intend to do more with them so I added them for now. You can even remove the parts that reference the package and just add the `Intent` you need inside each `case` if it makes it easier.